# How to add MPICH library to CLion project?

Tags: c++, cmake, mpi, clion, mpich

I downloaded the mpich-3.3.2 archive (stable release) from the [official site](http://www.mpich.org/downloads/), unpacked it and concluded that I have the MPICH library. But I can’t add it to Clion. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(MyProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER mpicc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpicxx)

add_executable(MyProject main.cpp)
```

I tried to enter different things in CMakeLists.txt, but always the same thing:

```
-- Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIB_NAMES MPI_C_HEADER_DIR MPI_C_WORKS) 
-- Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES MPI_CXX_HEADER_DIR MPI_CXX_WORKS)
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2019.3.4/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND MPI_CXX_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2019.3.4/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2019.3.4/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1700 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

What am I doing wrong? How should Clion find out the location of MPICH on my computer?

Comment: Have you added the path to the `bin` directory of MPICH to your `PATH` variable? If you open the command prompt and run `mpicc --show`, it should print some compiler options and not throw a command not found error. Also, the wrapper calls the actual compiler, so make sure that one is accessible too.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I have Windows. I read somewhere that MPICH does not work on Windows, and only MS MPI works (which I also can’t add to CLion). I do not see the bin directory in that archive from the official site.

Comment: If you have downloaded the `mpich-3.x.x.tar.gz` file from the MPICH site, this is the source code and you need to build it first. MS MPI and Intel MPI are both based on MPICH and I'd recommend you use one of them (also, both come with binary installers for Windows).

Comment: @HristoIliev, sorry, maybe stupid questions, I just never worked with MPI.
1) Yes, I downloaded mpich-3.x.x.tar.gz file from the MPICH site, but how "to build it first" this source code?
2) MS MPI by default adds the path to the bin directory in the PATH variable. But still, the result is “command not found”.
You wrote above, "Also, the wrapper calls the actual compiler, so make sure that one is accessible too." What does it mean?

Comment: 1. I have no idea how to build MPICH on Windows. There should be a Readme or similar file inside the archive with instructions. 2. It means that MPI relies on external compilers. Some implementations may not provide any compiler wrappers such as `mpicc` and you have to manually tell the compiler where the include files are and what libraries to additionally link. Intel MPI has such wrappers. Not sure about MS MPI though.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I hope it last stupid question. How to manually tell the compiler where the include files are and what libraries to additionally link?

Comment: In your project’s settings. Sorry, can’t help you with that since I’m a Visual Studio user.

Comment: @HristoIliev, good. Thank you for responding. Some points have cleared up. I'm just interesting why the Visual Studio? It’s heavy and slow, isn't it?) Is it true that parallel programming is better on Linux?

Comment: I’m simply used to VS and it supports all the languages I work in, except for the JVM languages, for which I use IntelliJ IDEA. VS is no heavier than IDEA. Besides, it has a free community version that covers all my personal needs and it also integrates well the Intel compilers and tools. But yeah, parallel programming (and programming in general) is better supported on Unix and Linux in particular.

Comment: @HristoIliev, if I put a virtual machine on which Linux will be, the speed of program execution will drop significantly compared to the speed of program execution on a real machine with Windows?

Comment: No. Only if the program does a lot of I/O.

Comment: @HristoIliev, if the program reads two matrices (up to 3000 x 3000 in size), then multiplies them and writes the result to a file, is that a lot of input / output?
that is, if I tracked the runtime of my program on different sizes of the matrix, then this time will not change on virtual Linux?

Comment: No, that's actually too little work for a parallel program, so don't worry. And the I/O will be buffered anyway.

Comment: @HristoIliev, what do you recommend to a Linux newbie, Debian or Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu. By the way, if you wait a bit, the May update of Windows 10 will bring WSL2, which is the Linux subsystem for Windows that runs a full blown Linux kernel in a lightweight virtual machine. Then you won't need to install a separate VM just to code under Linux.

Comment: @HristoIliev, just not everyone has a windows license to do updates) Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: @HristoIliev, One more small question.
You know how to make sure that the code before MPI_Init (& argc, & argv) and after MPI_Finalize () is executed in one process, and in several in between?
In the settings for the project, I registered 7 processes, and now all the code is executed in 7 processes, even which should be in one process.

Comment: With major cluster MPI implementations such as Open MPI or MPICH, all code executes in all processes. That's why MPI provides you with the process rank, but only after calling `MPI_Init()`, so you can make different processes do different things.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I ask you personally, because no many people know parallel programming on stack overflow

Comment: @HristoIliev, thanks, i got an idea!

Comment: There are many people here who understand parallel programming. You just have to make your questions visible to those people by not asking them as unrelated comments to an old question of yours.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I say that I see. Ok, now I’ll ask [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752531/why-dont-files-open-when-i-add-mpi) about parallel programming to the community, and not here personally to you, but hardly anyone will answer me